# Workbox Service Worker - Ignore external URL for caching?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I have a fairly simple service worker that will cache my requests and use `StaleWhileRevalidate`.
I have a handful of urls that will use `NetworkOnly` which does what I need.

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute('/login/*', new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly());
```

I have an ad file that is needed to show ads on the site. I don't want this to be cached so I've added a new route:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute('https://s.nitropay.com/ads-757.js', new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly());
```

However this causes issue with the service worker and no matter what workbox strategy I use for this, I will cause an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) no-response: no-response :: [{"url":"https://s.nitropay.com/ads-757.js"}]
    at Object.handle (https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.0.0/workbox-strategies.prod.js:1:1881)
```

This causes me to have no ads after the page is cached by the service worker.

How can I exclude this URL from being included in the service worker?

pwabuilder-sw.js file:

```
// This is the service worker with the Cache-first network
const CACHE = "pwabuilder-precache";

importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.0.0/workbox-sw.js');

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING") {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute('https://s.nitropay.com/ads-752.js', new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly());
workbox.routing.registerRoute('/login/*', new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly());
workbox.routing.registerRoute('/profile/*', new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly());
workbox.routing.registerRoute('/logout.php', new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly());
workbox.routing.registerRoute('/edit-deck/*', new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly());
workbox.routing.registerRoute('/deckbuilder/*', new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly());
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/*'),
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: CACHE
  })
);
```

Comment: Hello! Could you clarify whether you see the `no-response` message for `ads-757.js` all the time after the service worker is registered, including when online? Or do you only see it when you're offline?

Comment: Hi Jeff! I see it all the time after the service worker is registered (including online). I found one other similar issue and it seems to be related to adblocker on the web browser: https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=56734

Comment: Gotcha—If you're using an adblocking extension, that can definitely cause specific requests to fail. In general, adding a service worker won't change the behavior of the adblocker. So... it sounds like that's the explaination.